Clear Location (Remapped Windows Key to ALT Key) on Windows opens the Windows Game Bar
Is there any way on a Windows operating system (Windows 11, Blender 4.2) to stop it from opening the Game Bar when you press ALT+G to clear the location of an object? I dont want to remap this essential shortcut in Blender.
I have remapped my Windows Key to be the ALT key using PowerToys.

Are you sure that you're not pressing the Windows Logo Key instead of the Alt key? You might take a look at this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-for-game-bar-85d97243-c89b-1ae1-6402-0faf35d6489d#ID0EBD=Windows_11

Thank you for your response. Good point, I forgot to mention that I remapped the Windows Key to be the ALT key (using PowerToys)

Doe this link help? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-game-bar-shortcut-keys-in-windows-11/d07b3cbb-26da-4baa-a230-7920957a2db5
